# NSString&NSURL and Russian language

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

In my app I have an NSURL which is a file path. If a file or a folder's name contains Russian characters, instead of normal path, something like "/Users/user/Downloads/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5 %D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5 %D0%BD%D0%B0 %D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE.doc" is displayed.

Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour for NSURL, since file urls cannot contain special characters.

What are you trying to do with the URL? If you're using it do get a file from the system it should work. It seems like you're trying to display the path to the user, where and in what context?

Comment: I want to get a path of a file that the user has selected in an NSPathControl. Then I use url=[[pathControl clickedPathComponentCell] URL]; to get the file path and store the file in NSData

Comment: You want to use initWithContentsOfFile:?